# I have numeric string data with multiple "." i want to remove all "." EXCEPT the decimal point

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have some string representations of numbers that have "." as the thousand and decimal markers. I want to convert them to floats.

```
px =['1.410.00', '100.00', '1.000.00',  '1.000.000.00']

x = px[0]

def formatPxToFloat(pxStr):
    try:
        val = float(pxStr)
    except ValueError:
        val= float(re.sub("(\.)","", pxStr))   
    return val

formatPxToFloat(x)

#should return 1400.00 returns 140000
```

and have also tried other regex:

```
 r"(\d\.\d+)(?=\.\d+)"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards

George

Comment: I'm intrigued - the same separator for decimal point and thousands! Is this some country standard, or just a crazy format you've been given? What if there are three figures after the decimal point, how do they represent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
'\.(?=.*?\.)'
```

A breakdown of that regex is as follows:

```
\.    # '.'
(?=   # Positive lookahead
.*?   # Match anything
\.    # Search for '.'
```

Application in Python:

```
import pandas as pd

px = ['1.410.00', '100.00', '1.000.00',  '1.000.000.00']
px2 = pd.Series(px)
px3 = px2.str.replace(r'\.(?=.*?\.)', '')
print(px3)
```

Output:

```
0       1410.00
1        100.00
2       1000.00
3    1000000.00
dtype: object
```

Comment: I have also found a python package [link](https://pypi.org/project/money-parser/) that also works well with different regional price strings.

Answer (score 0):

With combination of `str.replace` and `str.count` functions:

```
px = ['1.410.00', '100.00', '1.000.00',  '1.000.000.00']
nums = [float(s.replace('.', '', s.count('.') - 1)) for s in px]
print(nums)
```

The output:

```
[1410.0, 100.0, 1000.0, 1000000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that the decimal point is always one followed by only two digits and the other points are always goint to be followed by 3 digis, you can use the regexp `\.(\d{3})`:

```py
>>> number = "2.000.999.91"
>>> re.sub("\.(\d{3})", r"\1", str)
'2000999.91'
```

The `r"\1"` part means, put the first capturing group, that in our case is `\d{3}` which means the three characters present after the point.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you could use `re.sub` to substitute your regular expression matches.

```
import re
px =['1.410.00', '100.00', '1.000.00',  '1.000.000.00']
px_floats = [float(re.sub(r'\.(?=.*?\.)', '', item)) for item in px]
for px_float in px_floats:
    print(f"value: {px_float}, type:  {type(px_float)}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
value: 1410.0, type:  <class 'float'>
value: 100.0, type:  <class 'float'>
value: 1000.0, type:  <class 'float'>
value: 1000000.0, type:  <class 'float'>
```